# How to break the while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

So I have been coding tic tac toe, but the issue is once one side gets 3, the function won't register and the code continues.  Can anyone give me insight to why this is happening?

I ran the code expecting it to break once a winner is decided, but it still continues past the win condition.  In the end of each of the win functions, I returned True and set the respective variables as True, but it seems it isn't registering the output of these functions because I printed the output of all once it was 3 in any and it returns True, but the if statement won't accept it for some reason.

```
board = [["-", "-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"] ]
win = False
count = 0
aa = None
bb = None
def printboard():
  print(board[0][0],"|", board[0][1],"|",board[0][2])
  print("_", "  _ ", " _ " )
  print(board[1][0],"|", board[1][1],"|",board[1][2])
  print("_", "  _ ", " _ ")
  print(board[2][0],"|", board[2][1],"|",board[2][2])
def row(board):
  for i in board:
    if i[0] == i[1] == i[2]:
      if i[0] == "x":
        aa = True
        return True
      if i[0] == "o":
        bb = True
        return True
  return False

def column(board):
  for j in range(0,3):
    if board[0][j] == board[1][j] == board[2][j]:
      if board[0][j] == "x":
        aa = True
        return True
      if board[0][j] == "o":
        bb = True
        return True
  return False

def diagonal(board):
  if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
    if board[0][0] == "x":
      aa = True
      return True
    if board[0][0] == "o":
      bb = True
      return True
  if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
     if board[0][2] == "x":
      aa = True
      return True
     if board[0][2] == "o":
      bb = True
      return True
  return False

while count < 10 and win == False:
  x1 = int(input("Choose row "))
  y1 = int(input("Choose column "))
  x2 = int(input("Choose row "))
  y2 = int(input("Choose column "))
  board[x1][y1] = "x"
  board[x2][y2] = "o"
  printboard()
  row(board)
  diagonal(board)
  print(row(board))
  print(column(board))
  print(diagonal(board))
  if row(board) is True or column(board) is True or diagonal(board) is True:
    if aa == True:
      print("Player 1 wins!")
      win = True
      break
    if bb == True:
      print("Player 2 wins!")
      win = True
      break
  else:
      continue
  count += 1
```

Comment: The `aa` and `bb` inside the `row`  and other functions is not the same as the global `aa` and `bb` unless you explicitly declare them `global` in the function definitions.

Comment: Using globals is not the best coding style. Consider explicitly returning values indicating whether X or O has filled a row/column/diagonal from those functions.

Comment: DO you mean returning something else to compare like integers?

Comment: It could return two booleans indicating whether X made 3-in-a-row and whether O made 3-in-a-row. Or a single character "X", "O", or "-" indicating which player made 3-in-arow. Or an Enum. Or ...

Comment: You received an answer below. Have you checked it? Any feedback for ripalo?

Answer (score 0):

On one glance, the issue is that your variable was a local variable (when it was within the function). Means that the aa or bb within the function does not affect the aa or bb located outside the code.

To do this, you need to declare the aa or bb variable as a global variable within the function.

I have included the code snippet for it to work below.

```
board = [["-", "-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"] ]
win = False
count = 0
aa = None
bb = None
def printboard():
  print(board[0][0],"|", board[0][1],"|",board[0][2])
  print("_", "  _ ", " _ " )
  print(board[1][0],"|", board[1][1],"|",board[1][2])
  print("_", "  _ ", " _ ")
  print(board[2][0],"|", board[2][1],"|",board[2][2])
def row(board):
    global aa
    global bb
    for i in board:
        if i[0] == i[1] == i[2]:
            if i[0] == "x":
                aa = True
                return True
            if i[0] == "o":
                bb = True
                return True
    return False

def column(board):
    global aa
    global bb
    for j in range(0,3):
        if board[0][j] == board[1][j] == board[2][j]:
            if board[0][j] == "x":
                aa = True
                return True
            if board[0][j] == "o":
                bb = True
                return True
    return False

def diagonal(board):
    global aa
    global bb
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        if board[0][0] == "x":
            aa = True
            return True
        if board[0][0] == "o":
            bb = True
            return True
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
        if board[0][2] == "x":
            aa = True
            return True
        if board[0][2] == "o":
            bb = True
            return True
    return False

while count < 10 and win == False:
  x1 = int(input("Choose row "))
  y1 = int(input("Choose column "))
  x2 = int(input("Choose row "))
  y2 = int(input("Choose column "))
  board[x1][y1] = "x"
  board[x2][y2] = "o"
  printboard()
  row(board)
  diagonal(board)
  print(row(board))
  print(column(board))
  print(diagonal(board))
  if row(board) is True or column(board) is True or diagonal(board) is True:
      print(f"aa status = {aa}")
      print(f"bb status = {bb}")
      if aa == True:
          print("Player 1 wins!")
          win = True
          break
      if bb == True:
          print("Player 2 wins!")
          win = True
          break
  else:
      continue
  count += 1
```